# `scipy.ndimage.zoom` vs `skimage.transform.rescale` with `order=0`

Tags: python, image, scipy, scikit-image

I'm creating a colour-over-grayscale image to show classification of image blocks. I need to upsample a low-resolution classification image to match the original image size, using zero-order.

When I use `skimage.transform.rescale(I,16,order=0)`, I get the desired result:
[image: rescale result]
However, when I use `scipy.ndimage.zoom(I,16,order=0)`, I get the following image with misalignment of the upsampled classification blocks and the original image patches (note the non-square blocks at the edges):
[image: zoom result]
My questions are:

1. Is this expected behaviour?
2. Why the difference?

I could see the `zoom` behaviour causing unexpected grief, since I only noticed it here with the obvious misalignment of blocks.

[edit 1]: [perhaps related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33721988/scipy-ndimage-zoom-result-depends-on-image-size).

[edit 2]: Should be able to pull [this repo](http://github.com/jessexknight/bayes-texture) and run python main.py with one of two imports at the top commented (flagged).

Comment: This doesn't seem right.  Can you post a link to your mask and the code that rescales it so that we can verify?

Comment: Thanks. I've added the link to the repo in the question.

Comment: This seems to be a subtlety of the way arrays are represented in the different libraries.  See the SciPy roadmap here: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blame/master/doc/ROADMAP.rst.txt#L176

Comment: Aha! Great find - thanks. You can post this as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: I think it is solved now, but in case people still need the answer but couldn't find it: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/scipy/scipy/d67829bf4f8885d85011a24b729c9fa763342b4b/doc/ROADMAP.rst.txt

Comment: Thanks, this is slightly more precise link: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/d67829bf4f8885d85011a24b729c9fa763342b4b/doc/ROADMAP.rst.txt#ndimage