# Unexpected behavior of `scipy.ndimage.zoom()` for `order=0`

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, zooming, ndimage

I have difficulties understanding the behavior of [`scipy.ndimage.zoom()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.3.3/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.zoom.html#scipy.ndimage.zoom) when `order=0`.

Consider the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import scipy.ndimage

arr = np.arange(3) + 1
print(arr)
for order in range(5):
    zoomed = sp.ndimage.zoom(arr.astype(float), 4, order=order)
    print(order, np.round(zoomed, 3))
```

whose output is:

```
0 [1. 1. 1. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 3. 3. 3.]
1 [1.    1.182 1.364 1.545 1.727 1.909 2.091 2.273 2.455 2.636 2.818 3.   ]
2 [1.    1.044 1.176 1.394 1.636 1.879 2.121 2.364 2.606 2.824 2.956 3.   ]
3 [1.    1.047 1.174 1.365 1.601 1.864 2.136 2.399 2.635 2.826 2.953 3.   ]
4 [1.    1.041 1.162 1.351 1.59  1.86  2.14  2.41  2.649 2.838 2.959 3.   ]
```

So, when `order=0` the values are (expectedly) not interpolated.
However, I was expecting to have:

```
[1. 1. 1. 1. 2. 2. 2. 2. 3. 3. 3. 3.]
```

i.e. exactly the same number of elements for each value, since the zoom is a whole number.
Hence, I was expecting to get the same result as [`np.repeat()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html#numpy.repeat):

```
print(np.repeat(arr.astype(float), 4))
[1. 1. 1. 1. 2. 2. 2. 2. 3. 3. 3. 3.]
```

Why is there a variation in the number of times each element gets repeated?

---

Note that `np.repeat()` does not directly work with multi-dimensional arrays and that is the reason why I would like to get the "correct" behavior from `scipy.ndimage.zoom()`.

---

My NumPy and SciPy versions are:

```
print(np.__version__)
# 1.17.4
print(sp.__version__)
# 1.3.3
```

---

I found this:
[`scipy.ndimage.zoom` vs `skimage.transform.rescale` with `order=0`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48211632/scipy-ndimage-zoom-vs-skimage-transform-rescale-with-order-0)
which points toward some unexpected behavior for `scipy.ndimage.zoom()` but I am not quite sure it is the same effect being observed.

Comment: I am not sure what shape you are trying to repeat, but maybe [`np.tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) works for you.

Comment: If you post a little example of input and output I can help you figuring out the syntax.

Comment: @Joe the OP is asking about the behaviour of a function in a Python library, not about how to achieve something in particular.

Comment: I am reading between the lines :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bin/edge array interpretation issue.
The behavior of `scipy.ndimage.zoom()` is based on the edge interpretation of the array values, while the behavior that would produce equally-sized blocks for integer zoom factors (mimicking `np.repeat()`) is based on the bin interpretation.

Let's illustrate with some "pictures".

## Bin Interpretation

Consider the array `[1 2 3]`, and let's assign each value to a bin.
The edges of each bin would be: `0` and `1` for `1`, `1` and `2` for `2`, etc.

```
0 1 2 3
|1|2|3|
```

Now, let's zoom this array by a factor of 4:

```
                    1 1 1
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2
|   1   |   2   |   3   |
```

Hence, the values to assign to the bins using the Next-door Neighbor method are:

```
                    1 1 1
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2
|1 1 1 1|2 2 2 2|3 3 3 3|
```

## Edge Interpretation

Consider the same array as before `[1 2 3]`, but now let's assign each value to an edge:

```
0 1 2
| | |
1 2 3
```

Now, let's zoom this array by a factor of 4:

```
                    1 1
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
| | | | | | | | | | | |
1          2          3
```

Hence, the values to assign to the edges using the Next-door Neighbor method are:

```
                    1 1
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
| | | | | | | | | | | |
1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3
```

and edge `3` is assigned to `2` because `2` has position `5.5` while `1` has position `0` and `(5.5 - 3 = 2.5) < (3 - 0 = 3)`.
Similarly, edge `8` is assigned to `2` because `(8 - 5.5 = 2.5) < (11 - 8 = 3)`.

---

## Comments

In Physics, the "bin array interpretation" is generally more useful, because measurements are typically "the result of some integration over a certain bin in an appropriate domain" (notably signal of any form -- including images -- collected at a given time interval), hence I was expecting a "bin interpretation" for `scipy.ndimage.zoom()` but I acknowledge that the "edge interpretation" is equally valid (although I am not sure which applications benefit the most from it).

---

(Thanks to @Patol75 for pointing me into the right [direction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59283603/5218354))

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is the expected behaviour.

Consider your initial list, `[1, 2, 3]`. You ask scipy to zoom on it 4 times, which thereby creates a 4x3=12 elements list. The first element of the list has to be 1, the last one has to be 3. Then, for 2, well we have an even number of elements, so it would make sense to have 2 as both the 6th and 7th elements. This gives `[1, , , , , 2, 2, , , , , 3]`. From here, you provided zoom with order=0, which means zoom is going to fill in for the missing values with splines of order 0. First case, zoom needs to fill in for 4 missing values between 1 and 2. This has to be `[1, 1, 2, 2]`. Second case, 4 missing values between 2 and 3. Same logic, `[2, 2, 3, 3]`. Final result `[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]`.

Now consider a 5x zoom, which generates a 15 elements array. Same story, except that there is a "middle" element, so that only one 2 is initially placed in the new list, at the 8th spot. With six elements to fill in between each pair, we get with the same logic `[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]`.

Therefore, you get more 2s than 1s or 3s because 2 is involved in two interpolation operations, opposed to one for both 1 & 3.

Comment: @norok2 My results are correct, you forgot to provide `order=0`. ;)

Comment: Sorry, my bad I was actually looking at the output of `np.repeat()` :$ with `order > 0` one would no longer get integer values to begin with.

Comment: Actually, if you give `[1, 2, 3]`, meaning a list of integers, whatever the order keyword value, the output is a list of integers as well. To get rid of integers, you need to provide a list of floats such as `[1., 2., 3.]` and give order a value greater or equal to 1. Interesting right?

Comment: that is because the results inherits the `dtype` of the input. That is why I actually forced the inputs to be `float` in the question.